# Azure AD B2C cost of migrating users

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I can't seem to find a written answer if B2C charges for migration of users?  Does anyone have a reference for this question?  Let's say I have 1 million users that I want to migrate over to B2C.  Will I get charged for each user after the 50k free users?
From looking at other questions about refresh tokens and other actions, and asking around it seems to only count against the quota if an ID or access token is issued.  Has anyone done this type of large migration of users in practice and not been charged?  A large portion of users are inactive and I don't want to incur charges for migrating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly I don't have experience of such a large migration, only some tens of thousands of users.

But according to docs, the Monthly Active Users (MAU) pricing model will only cost for users who authenticate within a given month (and 50 000 MAU are free).
Quoting from pricing page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/external-identities/):

> Who is considered a "monthly active user"?
>
> A monthly active user (MAU) is a unique user that performs an authentication within a given month. For example, a user that authenticates multiple times within a given month is counted as one MAU. Customers are not charged for a MAU’s subsequent authentications during the month, nor for inactive users.

Additionally:

> What is considered an authentication?
>
> Authentications may include:
>
> - Active, interactive login by the user;
> - Passive, non-interactive login (such as single sign-on, sign-up, sign-in, token refresh, and password change)
>
> Additional operations that are counted as an authentication include: login to a portal; redeeming an invitation; authenticating to perform an admin action; and when an application exchanges a refresh token for a new identity token or access token for that user.

So adding the users through Microsoft Graph API won't count as an "active user" nor an "authentication".
Having them sign in to reset their password as part of the migration would count.

So if your migration only involves creating the users through Graph API and not having the users sign in/reset their password, then they should not cost anything to you.

Comment: The sign-up part they mention in this line, is what caused me concern - Passive, non-interactive login (such as single sign-on, sign-up, sign-in, token refresh, and password change).  I see what you mean now though.  As long as I use the Graph API to migrate users I should be safe.  Thank you!

Comment: It’s free to create users with our api.